# App engine Local Unit test different instances [GO]

Tags: unit-testing, google-app-engine, go

I have an issue with testing separate methods, each test case is running on a different instance and address.

I'm looking for a way to set up the API address in order to preform the tests on the same API server.

I assuming that this warning is part of the issue.

```
WARNING  2015-11-04 18:15:25,003 devappserver2.py:779] DEFAULT_VERSION_HOSTNAME will not be set correctly with --port=0
```

This command will set the API server but I can't do the same for test...

```
dev_appserver.py .  --api_port 55555
```

Comment: Are you talking about testing with `aetest` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`aetest.NewInstance`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine/aetest#NewInstance) you can make sure that all your unit tests share a single instance:

```
var inst aetest.Instance

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
   var err error
   inst, err = aetest.NewInstance(nil)
   if err != nil {
       log.Fatalf("aetest.NewInstance: %v", err)
   }

   e := m.Run()
   inst.Close()
   os.Exit(e)
}

func TestMyTest(t *testing.T) {
   req, err := inst.NewRequest("GET", "/foo/bar", nil)
   // etc.
}
```

Comment: I tried but for some reason req is always nil 
this is my req 
r, err := inst.NewRequest("post", "api/cloud/v1/user", nil)

Comment: What is the value of `err`?

Comment: the vaule  of err is nil

Comment: and this is the value of r
&{post api/cloud/v1/user HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[] <nil> 0 [] false  map[] map[] <nil> map[]   <nil>}

Comment: You said above that "req is always nil", but that req is not nil. I don't really understand what problem you're having.